# iframe in selected tab not displaying on page refresh

Tags: jquery, iframe, tabs

There are a few similar posts, but none seem to refer to the iframe issue.  My jquery container has an iframe in each tab which loads on tab click.  As default, the first tab's iframe displays when container refreshed.  Using local storage I want to memorise the User's last selected tab.  My code in the 'Memorise tab' section (see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/01jurvpw/ ) works well in remembering the tab, but I can't get the iframe of that tab to immediately display on page refresh.  I probably need to .push the iframe somewhere, but I've really managed to confuse myself over how to adjust the code. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css



$(function() {

var mytabs = $('#RH_TabsTableShell').tabs();

function getSelectedTabIndex() {
  return mytabs.tabs('option', 'active'); }

beginTab = $("#RH_TabsTableShell ul li:eq(" + getSelectedTabIndex() + ")").find("a");
loadTabFrame($(beginTab).attr("href"), $(beginTab).attr("rel"));

$("a.tabref").click(function() {
  loadTabFrame($(this).attr("href"), $(this).attr("rel")); });

//tab switching function.  This grabs the “rel” attributes content when we click an <a> tag
function loadTabFrame(tab, url) {

  if ($(tab).find("iframe").length == 0) {
    var html = [];
    html.push('<div class="tabIframeWrapper">');
    html.push('<iframe class="iframetab" width="2000" scrolling="yes" src="' + url + '">Sorry, but your browser does not support frames.</iframe>');
    html.push('</div>');
    $(tab).append(html.join(""));
    $(tab).find("iframe").height($(window).height() - 80);
  }
  return false;
}

// ---------

// Memorise tab
$("#RH_TabsTableShell").tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        localStorage.selectedTab = ui.newTab.index() + 1;
    },
    active: localStorage.selectedTab ? localStorage.selectedTab - 1 : 0
});

})






<div id="RH_TabsTableShell">

    <ul id="RH_TabsTable" class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a class="tabref" href="#Table1" rel="https://bing.com">Table1</a></li>
      <li><a class="tabref" href="#Table2" rel="https://jsfiddle.net">Table2</a></li>
      <li><a class="tabref" href="#Table3" rel="https://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs">Table3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="Table1"> </div>
    <div id="Table2"> </div>
    <div id="Table3"> </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabs` natural behaviour will do much of what's necessary without needing to attach your own event handlers to the tabs.

However, it is convenient to attach custom event handlers to the panel elements, `#Table1` etc. so that the panels can be commanded to load their own content.

Also,

- `window.localStorage` can only be addressed via two methods `.setItem()` and `.getItem()`.
- the `activate` callback does not fire for the initial tab, and you need to have a `create` callback which loads the initial content.

```
$(function() {
    var preloadPanelContent = false; // set to true or false;

    var $panels = $("[id^='Table']").each(function(index) {
        $(this).on('loadContent', function(e) { // 'loadContent' is a custom event
            var src = $("#RH_TabsTable li a").get(index).rel;
            if (!$(this).find('iframe').length) {
                $(this).html('<div class="tabIframeWrapper"><iframe class="iframetab" width="2000" scrolling="yes" src="' + src + '">Sorry, but your browser does not support frames.</iframe></div>').find('iframe').height($(window).height() - 80);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#RH_TabsTableShell').tabs({
        'active': window.localStorage.getItem('selectedTab') || 0,
        'activate': function(event, ui) {
            ui.newPanel.trigger('loadContent'); // tell the panel to load its content (if not already loaded).
            window.localStorage.setItem('selectedTab', ui.newTab.index());
        },
        'create': function(event, ui) {
            ui.panel.trigger('loadContent'); // tell the initial panel to load its content (if not already loaded).
        }
    });

    if(preloadPanelContent) {
        $panels.trigger('loadContent');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4oost8wg/)**

Comment: Thanks, but I get {"error": "Please use POST request"}.  I'm afraid I'm too much of a noob to understand what to do with this

Comment: Hmm, I confess it's been a while since I used `tabs`. I'm rather bust right now but should be able to take another look at this in a few hours.

Comment: OK, I've revised the code. See if it's any better now.

Comment: Well the tabs container appears, but unfortunately the iframe doesn't load on start-up and the tabs don't memorise.

Comment: I just made a mod. Try it again.

Comment: Sorry, same result as my last comment.  Just to check, I'm replacing all my original jquery with yours - I assume this is correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149832/discussion-between-roamer-1888-and-silverburch).

Comment: OK, it took a while but I cracked it. See latest, including DEMO link.

Comment: That works great, and really efficient too.  Much appreciate the time and effort you put in to this. I'd have never got there.